# Why Tomcat installed in the project directory of a web application (java)

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have seen a couple(or more) of real time web application project structure and ***I have noticed the tomcat folder structure was placed inside the web application project folder***. I understand one point that if we use any build tool like maven or ant in building our project then the build will directly publish the changes that we do to our project to the tomcat which was placed inside the current project directory.

So My question/curiosity is what are the other advantages in following this approach. What approach one should follow if they have to build another web application in the same system? Do I need to create another tomcat instance inside my 2nd web project with different port number or should I configure( I am not sure how to do that) my 2nd project to build the application to the same Tomcat of the 1st application?

What are the advantages and disadvantages in following this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROS**

*Less Codes, Less Libraries*

When we use two or more project in a tomcat it can be use same libraries in tomcat/lib folder. If we need only Oracle JDBC Driver for connection we can add this jar to lib folder and all application use it. It very nice for MAVEN too. (**But don't forget**: you have to import maven or another libraries to tomcat lib folder if you put them your application path other applications can not read )

*Less Management*

There is only one tomcat, one error log, one system log. You can not need to search other tomcats. All info in the one tomcat folder (console).

*Seperate Server*

You can use one tomcat with seperate servers and you can define which application run in which server.

**CONS**

*Memory Leak*

In one tomcat, **more application** means **more memory request** .You can define memory size with some attributes but sometimes tomcat can not handle that memory leak and stopped.

*Slow Starting Time*

More application means more initialize time. When you start your tomcat it has to run all applications.

*Complexity*

Let's think you need to define a RewriteRule for mapping. If you have two application you have be careful for other applications. It can be define for mapping, auth, url forwarding, url blocking etc.

Also you can not find in log. Which log belongs which application. (You can use log4j for that or you can use seperate server)

*Applications are seperate but also they are attached*

When you fail in a common libraries all applications will be fail. When you write `while(true)` all apllications will be slow and shutdown for memory leak.

Comment: Excellent got more info then what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You just simply add another war into your **webbapps** folder in running tomcat directory. On your default url will be application with name ROOT (ROOT.war) eg. `address:8080/`, another will be like /tmp for tmp.war eg.`address:8080/tmp` Tomcat can handle a lot of separate applications.

**pros and cons?**

If you share tomcat for more applications you have to consider that more **application** mean more **resources** (Memory, CPU usage etc.) and this resources are shared. If you need to have application which need a lot of resources than deploy your application to separate tomcat on separate server.

Also consider if you want to restart tomcat for one application every of them will be unavailable. More applications mean also longer start of the tomcat.